# Getting command line option value that contains "\n"(newline), apache commons cli

Tags: java, apache-commons-cli

I use apache-commons-cli:

```
String topic = commandLine.getOptionValue('t').trim()
```

to get option value from command line :

```
-t abcd\n
```

,which gets an escaped topic with value

```
abcd\\n
```

But for my special case , I really need a string "abcd\n" without escape.

How can I pass the correct value from command line?

Comment: Can't you "escape" it like "\\n" ?

Comment: I need a char without escape, but cli give me an escaped one.